# Unable to add @TypeConverters in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

I am trying to use type converters to store list of String and list of some other object into the database. I implemented the `@TypeConverter` and tried most of the mentioned method but nothing seems to be working currently. What I am doing wrong here ? Any help would be appreciated.

**Converter**

```
class FloorsConverter {

    //Converter for converting a list of String to String
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToString(value: List<String>): String {
        return listToString(value)
    }

    //Converter for converting a list of TimeEntity to a String
    @TypeConverter
    fun listOfTimeEntityToString(value: List<TimeEntity>): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```

**Enitity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "floor_profile")
class FloorProfileEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "profile_name")
    val profileName: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "chosen_floors")
    @field:TypeConverters(FloorsConverter::class)
    val chosen_floors: List<String>? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")
    @field:TypeConverters(FloorsConverter::class)
    val startEndRunningTime: List<TimeEntity>? = null
)
```

**Log Error**

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

private final java.util.List<java.lang.String> chosen_floors = null;
```

Note: I have also tried adding `@TypeConverters` annotation in the database class but it still doesn't work. Similarly I have tried adding `@TypeConverters` at the top of Entity class itself which also doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477939/6819340

Comment: Yeah, It's not working

Comment: you have done the list  to string convertor but not the string to list. Add that also.

Comment: @Sagar, Thanks a lot it worked. May I get the reason for this? Even though I don't need the second conversion what is the need to add this?

Comment: You need to be able to convert when storing the data and then, when extracting the data to reverse the conversion. So for every Type (object) to be converted you need two converters. The first (to store the data) must convert the data into a type that can be handled (stored in SQlite), typically a String e.g **from TheType to String** and then when retrieving data you need one that converts from the **String to TheType**.

Comment: So it's like a convention that has to be followed when working with `@TypeConverters`? So let's say I just want to insert data into the database and never wants to read it, in that case I would still need to define  a function which converts that `String` to `TheType` (even though I don't need that)